# How to add python keyword terms as tag attributes in lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, keyword

I'm using lxml to build an XML based on some data.

```
    root = etree.Element('sentences')
for item in aspectSentenceList:
    print item
    sentenceTag = etree.SubElement(root, "sentence", id=item[0])
    textTag = etree.SubElement(sentenceTag, "text", text=item[1])
    aspectTermsTag = etree.SubElement(sentenceTag, "aspectTerms")
    for asp in item[2]:
        aspectTermTag = etree.SubElement(aspectTermsTag, "aspectTerm", term = asp[0], frm = asp[1], to = asp[2])
```

The catch is in last line. There are three attributes, **term**, **from** and **to**. The issue is, python wouldn't let me use "from" keyword for any tasks other than usual imports. Though I have done temporary workaround by using **frm** instead of **from**, and replace all such strings later. However how can I do this without trustless hacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh got it just within five minutes after posting the question. The documentation mentions that attributes are python dictionaries. I updated the last line with:-

```
aspectTermTag = etree.SubElement(aspectTermsTag, "aspectTerm", {"term":asp[0], "from": asp[1], "to":asp[2]})
```